# The inherited method Object.clone() cannot hide the public abstract method

Tags: java, generics, compiler-construction

So, I have this bit of wild, crazy code, that is making the compiler spit in my face for some hours the following error:

```
The inherited method Object.clone() cannot hide the public abstract method in IOrderable<T>
```

The culprit classes are the following (the error appears right in the T of the generic):

```
public class MyInterval<T extends Xpto & Successorable<T>> implements Cloneable {
    public MyInterval<T> clone(){
        MyInterval<T> it = null;
        try {
            it = (MyInterval<T>) super.clone();
            it.max = it.max.clone();
            it.min = (T) it.min.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return it;
    }
}

public interface Xpto {}

public interface Successorable<Y> extends IOrderable<Y> {
    Y suc();    
}   

interface IOrderable<J> extends Rankable<J>, Cloneable {
    boolean greaterEq(J e);
    J clone();
}

public interface Rankable<P> {
    int rank(P e);
}
```

Yes, they seem kinda random. They solely exist to test some weird things in a compiler/java_byte_code_instrumentation-like project I am doing. How can I make this work while keeping the logic intact?

Thanks

Comment: Hello Jon. The first one, right on the T (of the generic).

Comment: Works for me.  1.6 and 1.5.  Eclipse.

Comment: Yes. Several people of my team can run this on their computers too. Don't know why but not all Eclipse programs run the same compiler. We all have similar Eclipse installations and while they can run this code, I can't. Mine seems to be stricter than theirs.

Comment: @devoured: Now I've tried it (requires lots of files, curse Java) I'm getting a similar problem. No idea why yet...

Comment: I've also tried to make IOrderable not implement Cloneable, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Try getting rid of J clone();

Comment: @alpha: I need a visible(public) clone so that other classes can call this clone() method.

Comment: I even tried using separate compile units (given generics).  still works fine.  Agree that it smells like compiler and spec level (generics) compliance.  I think you should include the details of your compiler.

Comment: Note also tests fine with javac javac 1.6.0_24 on mac os x. (I'm removing my answer which was just a temp code dump.)

Comment: where can I get info about my compiler?

Comment: It looks like the types of your clone method are not compatible ... or not every compiler will know that they are compatible.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue here. I think (as the error suggests) that it is related with method visibility.

Comment: Tbh, this seems more like a bug. Commenting out Xpto from the first line will make this pass.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what Jdk versions exhibit what behavior 32 bit vs 64?. Any special jvm or compiler args?

Comment: @devoured: Not sure if it will help with this specific case, but you might be interested in Kohsuke Kawaguchi's [Bridge Method Injector](http://kohsuke.org/2010/08/07/potd-bridge-method-injector/), which works as a bytecode post-processor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I encountered the same compilation error, and as far as I can tell, this is an edge case in the specification for intersection types (multiply-bound generic types), and there is no solution possible.

A small test case:

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    public Object clone();
}

public interface InterfaceB {}

public class ClassA<T extends InterfaceA> {} // ok

public class ClassB<T extends InterfaceA & InterfaceB> {} //not ok
```

You can't have an intersection type containing any interfaces containing any method whose signature matches a non-public method on the base class (in this case, implicitly Object).  This is not specific to Object or clone, however:

```
public abstract class Base {
    protected abstract void m();
}

public interface Interface {
    public void m();
}

public class Class<T extends Base & Interface> {} // not ok
```

[Here's the relevant Oracle bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6946211), marked as "Not a defect".

[Here's the relevant Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314556), where the compiler was modified to produce the same error to match javac.  This appears to have been a change for Indigo 3.7, which explains why some people could reproduce and others couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

I think [this tutorial](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#How%20does%20type%20erasure%20work%20when%20a%20type%20parameter%20has%20several%20bounds?) explains the problem and you should be able to figue out a solution.  The problem is when a type parameter has several bounds.

The below code replicates the error.

```
interface Xpto
{
}

interface Xable < T >
{
    T clone ( ) ;
}

class MyStuff < S extends Xpto & Xable < S > >
{
}
```

However the below code is basically the same but without the compiler error.

```
interface Xpto
{
}

interface Xable < T > extends Xpto
{
    T clone ( ) ;
}

class MyStuff < S extends Xable < S > >
{
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a different error with this: `clone() in java.lang.Object cannot implement clone() in Xable; attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public`.
Also, FWIW, making `Xable` an abstract class with an abstract `clone` method fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem implementing clone as public

Comment: How did you implement a method in an interface?

Comment: So, you say methods from inherited interface and class (what in C++ we call virtually inherited) shall have same signature and visibility? Would make sense. At least this solves the problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too, however I think I came to it a bit differently....

the following code works fine: (it is nested within another class, so the interface did not need to have public methods).

```
interface A{}
class B{
    class C extends B implements A{ }
}
```

the problem occurs when you add a non-public method into interface A, and implement it non-publically in class B.

```
interface A{
    void doeet();

}

class B{
    void doeet(){};
    class C extends B implements A{
    }
}
```

Looking at your code, it seems to be similar in that some of the methods in the interfaces haven't been declared public.

Comment: You said: "the problem occurs when you add a non-public method into interface A, and implement it non-publically in class B."

Can I ask you a question for I'm new to Java. As far as I know, all methods in an interface must be marked as "public" or "abstract". Even if , we don't marked them as "public" , it is implicitly declared as public in order to be visible for the implementing classes.

So how can we "add a non-public method in interface A" as you said?
Do I misunderstand anything? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

In my case I forgot the public keyword in front of a method that had to be implemented as the class containing it implemented an interface defining it.